# Is it possible to track outgoing calls and sms?

Tags: iphone, ios

We'd like to create an app to track the amount of outgoing sms aswell as the length of outgoing calls (so the user can track his expenses, set limits for warnings etc). I did some googleing but did not find any hint. There is one app that achieves the same but requires jailbreak (which is not an option for us).

It would be perfectly fine to track the number of sms and the length of outgoing calls only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It isn't possible to do this without jailbreaking the device (at time of writing, iOS 4.3.5).

Comment: Thanks mate, that's sad :/ Any workaround you know of except jailbreaking?

Comment: http://www.mspy.com/buynow.html?utm_expid=77466971-48.PiOcvobASCy8uwRkDaBT9A.0&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mspy.com%2Fno-jailbreak.html    How mspy does it?

Comment: @Durgaprasad mSpy only allows you to track sms and other stuff only if u know iCloud id of target device. If you have iCloud then there is no need for this app. You know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there only is the [Core Telephony framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html), which lets you know the id of a call and if its dialing, incomming or connected.